Variadic template with type checking in C++
I need to have an interface to the driver that provides a set of send() functions only of the following types:
void send(u8 a);
void send(u8 a, u8 b);
void send(u8 a, u8 b, u8 c);
void send(u8 *a, u32 size);

I want to shorten the appearance of this interface and implement it using variable templates.
As you can see, it is required, firstly, to check whether the first argument is a pointer, and if so, then handle this case separately. In other cases, you must prevent entering more than 3 arguments of type u8 (unsigned char).
I'm completely confused with the use of enable_if, SFINAE, etc.
My example:
template<typename ...Args>
void send(Args... args) {
}

void send(u8 *p, u32 size) {
}

int main() {
  u8 b;

  send(1);              // OK
  send(1, 2);           // OK
  send(1, 2, 3);        // OK

  send('1', '2', 3, 4); // NOT OK: 4 arguments were passed, I need a maximum of 3

  send(&b, 10);         // NOT OK: call template 'send', not specialized 'send(u8 *p, u32 size)'
}

Is this possible?

"I want to shorten the appearance of this interface and implement it using templates." Overload is simple and clear. You can use one template function instead, but SFINAE/concept to express the same restriction,would be verbose too (and "complex"). In addition, as template, you have to provide implementation in header, (or use explicit instantiation... but in that case, regular overload is simpler again).

I second the first comment, keep the overloads.  Anything you do yourself is basically going to reinvent the wheel of the resolution but now you have to explicitly spell it all out.

its a variadic template. Variable templates are something different: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template

Try something like this:
void send() {} // do nothing

void send(u8 *a, u32 size) {
    ...
}

template<typename... Args>
void send(u8 arg, Args... args) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Args) <= 2, "No more than 3 args allowed!");
    // use arg as needed, then...
    send(args...); // send the rest...
}

Alternatively:
void send(u8 *a, u32 size) {
    ...
}

template<typename... Args>
void send(u8 arg, Args... args) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Args) <= 2, "No more than 3 args allowed!");
    // use arg as needed, then...
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) > 0) {
        send(args...); // send the rest...
    }
}

However, one gotcha with this approach is that something like send(1, &b, 10); would be accepted. It would process arg=1 and then call send(&b, 10). If you want to avoid that, you can use additional template trickery to ensure that all of the variadic parameters are the same type, see:
Specifying one type for all arguments passed to variadic function or variadic template function w/out using array, vector, structs, etc?
Is there a way to define a variadic number of arguments of the same type?

Yes, it is possible to express the restriction with SFINAE/concept, something like:
template <typename ...Args>
void send(Args...)
requires (
    (sizeof...(Args) == 1  && (std::is_convertible_v<Args, u8> && ...))
    || (sizeof...(Args) == 2
        && ((std::is_convertible_v<Args, u8> && ...)
            || (std::is_convertible_v<std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<Args...>>, u8*> &&
                std::is_convertible_v<std::tuple_element_t<1, std::tuple<Args...>>, u32>)
            )
        )
    || (sizeof...(Args) == 3 && (std::is_convertible_v<Args, u8> && ...))
)
{
    // if constexpr (dispatch on above conditions)
}

Demo
But overload is simpler and clearer.
In addition, as template, you have to provide implementation in header, (or use explicit instantiation... but in that case, regular overload is simpler again).

This is very easy to do in C++20.
You can leave the overload taking a pointer as is, and add a variadic template with some constraints to handle everything else:
#include <concepts>

// type-constraint for each template argument
template <std::convertible_to<u8> ...Args>
// and also a requires-clause that limits the amount of arguments
  requires (sizeof...(Args) != 0 && sizeof...(Args) <= 3)
void send(Args... args) {
    // ...
}

void send(u8 *p, u32 size) {
    // ...
}

If you're using C++17, you can do the same thing by using std::enable_if and fold expressions, it just wouldn't be as pretty.
Radical alternative
This is how I would actually design this interface.
Have a single function taking std::span:
void send(std::span<const u8> data);

std::array<u8, 2> a{1, 2};
send(a);

You should generally prefer an overload taking a std::span over a pointer and a size.
If you have such an overload, you can also just make the user put their data into a temporary array instead of letting send handle that feature.
